# Can we run any user defined function before the main function?

Tags: c

I want to run a user defined function before the main function in C. But I don't know how to do that. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (again). Why would you want to do that? You could simply put a function call at the beginning of your main function. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MatthiasW.: On bare-metal embedded systems that can be required to initialise memory controller, CPU, etc. But that is implementation specific.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the answer is no.

For an application there is normally no reason to, you simply run any initialization functions, at the top of `main()` before going into the real application code.

The exceptions usually involve shared libraries. Those can have initialization and termination functions defined that execute after the `libc` initialization is done but before `main()` is called, or after `main()` has returned (or the program is otherwise exited) and before the process terminates.

It is going to be heavily dependent on the OS and `libc` implementation. On Linux for `glibc` this [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/miscellaneous.html) has some info.